# What is #app means in reactjs in HTML code?

Tags: html, reactjs

In some codes I saw that instead of using div they used only #app and call in ReactDOM. What is this syntax for?

HTML:

```
 #app
```

React:

```
 ReactDOM.render(
     <App />,
   document.getElementById('app')
 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's hard to say with just the info you've given, but it looks like the HTML file is a Jade file. [Jade is an HTML templating engine](http://jade-lang.com/), essentially a template tool that let's you write HTML in a shorter syntax. If you look at the "id & classes" examples in [this post](https://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/), you can see that by simply writing `#content` Jade will convert it to `<div id="content">...`

So in your case, `#app` would get converted to `<div id="app" />`, which is the element the React will be rendered into.

Comment: @user6642297 You're welcome. Remember if a response answers your question, please mark it as the right answer so everyone know's it's resolved :)